# How can I fix android error in delphi database and bluetooth?

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth

I have problem with connect to bluetooth in android version of my app, how i can fix it?
i think can not access to database for send data to bluetooth device.

```
procedure TFrmMain.SendData(ByReciveData: Boolean = True; Start: Integer = 0);
var
  DataStr, CBAddress, BlueName: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if CustomerReport.IsEmpty then
    Exit;
  DataStr := CompareDataToSend(Start);
  CBAddress := CustomerReportBlueAddress.Value;
  BlueName := CustomerReport.FieldByName('BlueName').AsString;
  CBAddress := CustomerReport.FieldByName('BlueAddress').AsString;
  if Pie7.Fill.Color = TAlphaColors.red then
  begin
    CustomerReport.DisableControls;
    CustomerReport.AfterScroll := nil;
    VtblTest.Open;
    VtblTest.Clear;
    VtblTest.Assign(CustomerReport);
    CustomerReport.AfterScroll := CustomerReportAfterScroll;
    CustomerReport.EnableControls;
    for i := 1 to FormMain.ListDevice.GetCount do
    begin
      BlueName := FormMain.ListDevice.DeviceNames[i];
      CBAddress := FormMain.ListDevice.DeviceAddress[i];
      // SendDataBluetooth('ID=' + BlueName + '?' + DataStr, BlueName, CBAddress,
      // ByReciveData);
      VtblTest.Locate('BlueName', BlueName, []);
      if VtblTest.FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger > 0 then
        SendDataToBluetooth(BlueName, CBAddress, DataStr, ByReciveData);
    end;
  end
  else
    SendDataToBluetooth(BlueName, CBAddress, DataStr, ByReciveData);
  // SendDataBluetooth('ID=' + BlueName + '?' + DataStr, BlueName, CBAddress,
  // ByReciveData);
end;**
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the needed permisions in project options to access Bluetooth? [Uses Permissions](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Uses_Permissions)

Comment: yes the permissions is ok

Comment: i connect to bluetooth but i cant send data for micro